# Maintaining :active class after customizing Carousel indicators

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

After removing the class carousel-indicators from the ol tag the active class doesn't cycle through my li's anymore. The reason I removed carousel-indicators class was because I want to replace the dots with letters.

**Edit: To clarify, my carousel indicators are no longer highlighted when the slides are active my question is how do I achieve that after removing the carousel-indicator class.**

```css
section {
  text-align: center;
}

section>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: italic;
  font-family: sans;
  font-size: 1.8vh;
}

section>ul>li {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 25px;
}

section>ul>li:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

section>ul>li:active {
  color: red;
}

.carousel-content {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section>

  <!-- Indicators (outside)-->
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li data-target="#about-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">H</li>
    <li data-target="#about-carousel" data-slide-to="1">M</li>
    <li data-target="#about-carousel" data-slide-to="2">V</li>
    <li data-target="#about-carousel" data-slide-to="3">P</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="about-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <div class="carousel-content">
          <ul>
            <li class="carouselTitle">
              <h2>Historia</h2>
            </li>
            <li class="carouselBody">
              Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="carousel-content">
          <ul>
            <li class="carouselTitle">
              <h2></h2>
            </li>
            <li class="carouselBody">
              Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="carousel-content">
          <ul>
            <li class="carouselTitle">
              <h2></h2>
            </li>
            <li class="carouselBody">
              Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="carousel-content">
          <ul>
            <li class="carouselTitle">
              <h2></h2>
            </li>
            <li class="carouselBody">
              Property and building packaging
              <br>
              <br> Packaging Infrastructure
              <br>
              <br> Vehicles for local transport
              <br>
              <br> Vacum Cooler
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#about-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#about-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you asking about why it doesn't automatically start on its own or something else? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I purposely added the data-interval="false", my question is how can (after removing the carousel-indicator class) I keep the indicator focused or active class when the corresponding slide is active. So when the second slide is active, I want the second indicator to be highlighted.